# Moving folders with more than 5 files in to another folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder G:\Test\Accounts that has 10 other sub-folders e.g. G:\Test\Accounts\New Customers”, “G:\Test\Accounts\Existing Customers”, “G:\Test\Accounts\Retired Customers”…….etc.

If any of these sub-folders have more than 5 files in them, I want to move them into another folder and if it has less than 5 files, do nothing.  I tried with the script below but it doesn’t move the folders only counts the number of files in each sub folders. How do I get it to move the sub-folders and not just count it pls?Thanks

$NoOfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path G:\Test\Accounts* | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $*.FullName $(Get-ChildItem $* | Measure-Object).Count}

If($NoOfFiles -gt “5”)
{
Move-Item -destination “G:\Test\Regular Customers”
}
Else
{
Break
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, using a *single pipeline*:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory G:\Test\Accounts | 
  Where-Object { ($_ | Get-ChildItem -File).Count -gt 5 } |
  Move-Item -Destination 'G:\Test\Regular Customers'
```

- `Get-ChildItem -Directory G:\Test\Accounts` enumerates all *subdirectories* of `G:\Test\Accounts`
- `($_ | Get-ChildItem -File).Count` counts the number of *files* in each subdirectory.
- Because the `-gt 5` test is performed in the context of a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call, only those subdirectories that contain more than 5 files are passed through to the [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) call.